# How to handle categorical variables in sklearn GradientBoostingClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

I am attempting to train models with [GradientBoostingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) using categorical variables.

The following is a primitive code sample, just for trying to input categorical variables into `GradientBoostingClassifier`.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
import pandas

iris = datasets.load_iris()
# Use only data for 2 classes.
X = iris.data[(iris.target==0) | (iris.target==1)]
Y = iris.target[(iris.target==0) | (iris.target==1)]

# Class 0 has indices 0-49. Class 1 has indices 50-99.
# Divide data into 80% training, 20% testing.
train_indices = list(range(40)) + list(range(50,90))
test_indices = list(range(40,50)) + list(range(90,100))
X_train = X[train_indices]
X_test = X[test_indices]
y_train = Y[train_indices]
y_test = Y[test_indices]

X_train = pandas.DataFrame(X_train)

# Insert fake categorical variable. 
# Just for testing in GradientBoostingClassifier.
X_train[0] = ['a']*40 + ['b']*40

# Model.
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.01,max_depth=8,n_estimators=50).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The following error appears:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'b'
```

From what I gather, it seems that [One Hot Encoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn-preprocessing-onehotencoder) on categorical variables is required before `GradientBoostingClassifier` can build the model.

Can `GradientBoostingClassifier` build models using categorical variables without having to do one hot encoding?

R gbm package is capable of handling the sample data above. I'm looking for a Python library with equivalent capability.

Comment: You do need to use a OneHotEncoder. Then this should not be a problem. Also, don't put pandas DataFrames into scikit-learn estimators, you should use numpy arrays (by calling np.array(dataframe) or dataframe.values).

Comment: There is [work in progress](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3346) to allow this.

Comment: Same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24715230/166749).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[pandas.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) or [statsmodels.tools.tools.categorical](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.tools.tools.categorical.html) can be used to convert categorical variables to a dummy matrix. We can then merge the dummy matrix back to the training data.

Below is the example code from the question with the above procedure carried out.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve,auc
from statsmodels.tools import categorical
import numpy as np

iris = datasets.load_iris()
# Use only data for 2 classes.
X = iris.data[(iris.target==0) | (iris.target==1)]
Y = iris.target[(iris.target==0) | (iris.target==1)]

# Class 0 has indices 0-49. Class 1 has indices 50-99.
# Divide data into 80% training, 20% testing.
train_indices = list(range(40)) + list(range(50,90))
test_indices = list(range(40,50)) + list(range(90,100))
X_train = X[train_indices]
X_test = X[test_indices]
y_train = Y[train_indices]
y_test = Y[test_indices]


###########################################################################
###### Convert categorical variable to matrix and merge back with training
###### data.

# Fake categorical variable.
catVar = np.array(['a']*40 + ['b']*40)
catVar = categorical(catVar, drop=True)
X_train = np.concatenate((X_train, catVar), axis = 1)

catVar = np.array(['a']*10 + ['b']*10)
catVar = categorical(catVar, drop=True)
X_test = np.concatenate((X_test, catVar), axis = 1)
###########################################################################

# Model and test.
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.01,max_depth=8,n_estimators=50).fit(X_train, y_train)

prob = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]   # Only look at P(y==1).

fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, prob)
roc_auc_prob = auc(fpr, tpr)

print(prob)
print(y_test)
print(roc_auc_prob)
```

Thanks to Andreas Muller for instructing that pandas Dataframe should not be used for scikit-learn estimators.

Answer (score -5):

Sure it can handle it, you just have to encode the categorical variables as a separate step on the pipeline. Sklearn is perfectly capable of handling categorical variables as well as R or any other ML package. The R package is still (presumably) doing one-hot encoding behind the scenes, it just doesn't separate the concerns of encoding and fitting in this case (as it arguably should).

Comment: Afaik some R libraries handle categorical variables natively. In a decision tree, using one-hot encoding is different from doing a categorical variable. Sklearn only works on numpy arrays, which don't allow mixed types.