# I'm trying to build a random forest classifier upon a liver disorder data set. But the fit method returns an error as such:

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, dataset, classification, data-analysis

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0,1,len(df)) <= 0.75
train, test = df[df['is_train'] == True], df[df['is_train'] == False]
features = df.columns[:10]
y = pd.factorize(train['Selector'])[0]
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs = 2, random_state = 0)
clf.fit(train[features],y)
```

---

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 clf.fit(train[features],y)
>
> C:\Users\abhir\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.pyc
>   in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
>       244         """
>       245         # Validate or convert input data
>   --> 246         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
>       247         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csc', ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
>       248         if sample_weight is not None:
>
> C:\Users\abhir\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc
>   in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy,
>   force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
>   ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
>       400                                       force_all_finite)
>       401     else:
>   --> 402         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
>       403
>       404         if ensure_2d:
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: Male
>
> ---

Any help on why is this happening and how to resolve this? link to [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/ILPD+(Indian+Liver+Patient+Dataset))

Answer (score 0):

Scikit learn's RandomForestClassifier doesn't support categorical data, like in your case 'gender' with values 'Male' and 'Female': See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715230/can-sklearn-random-forest-directly-handle-categorical-features) question for details.

To solve that problem, you could encode the categorical variable with a label encoder:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(['Male', 'Female'])
df.loc[:,'gender'] =  le.transform(df['gender'])
```

The dataset also contains some NaN in the column Alkphos which you would need to handle before training the classifier. The easiest but not necessarily the best option is to remove the datasets with missing values:

```
df = df[np.isfinite(df['Alkphos'])]
```

You need to do this preprocessing before splitting the data into training and test set, so both data sets undergo the same transformation and filtering.