# Can sklearn random forest classifier handle categorical variables?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I found [this thread from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715230/can-sklearn-random-forest-directly-handle-categorical-features) and the answer states that no, sklearn random forest classifier cannot handle categorical variables (or at least not directly). Has the answer changed in 2020?

I want to feed `gender` as a feature for my model. However, `gender` can take on three values: `M`, `F` of `np.nan`. If I encode this column into three dichotomous columns, how can the random forest classifier know that these three columns represent a single feature?

Imagine `max_features` = 7. When training a given tree, it will randomly randomly pick seven features. Suppose `gender` was chosen. If `gender` is split into three columns (`gender_M`, `gender_F`, `gender_NA`), will the random forest classifier always pick all three columns and count it as one feature, or is there a chance that it will only pick one or two?

Comment: Any model can handle categorical data encoded properly (For ex. One0hot encoding)

Comment: Yeah, but one hot encoding turns one column into multiple columns...

Comment: Yes. And I dont see any harm in that.

Comment: If only one of the columns is selected when training a tree, the tree will only make splits based on *one* category from then entire range of categories.

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava inflating the number of features is indeed an issue; I suggest you think it more closely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `max_features` is set to a value lower than the actual amount of columns (which is the advisable approach, see the recommended values for `max_features` in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)), then yes, there is a chance that for a given *estimator* in the random forest only a subset of the dummy columns is considered.

But that is not necessarily too bad. In decision trees, a feature is selected as *node* at a given level aiming at optimizing some metric, independently from the other features, that is, only considering the actual feature and the target. So in a sense the model will not treat these dummy columns as *belonging to the same feature*.

In general though, the best approach for binary features is to come up with an appropriate method to fill missing values, and convert it into a single column encoded to `0`s and `1`s.

Comment: All correct, but a reminder should be arguably added that, as a rule, `max_features` is indeed set to a value (possibly much) lower than the total number of features. This in fact was one of the very innovative characteristics of RF; see [Why is Random Forest with a single tree much better than a Decision Tree classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239242/why-is-random-forest-with-a-single-tree-much-better-than-a-decision-tree-classif)

Comment: AFAIK randomness in the selection of features in the individual trees benefits the overall classification, since it brings down the bias. Though I can't see how that would be the case with a single estimator? I mean, I agree with your point, but looking into the post, I'm picturing an example where each feature is relevant, and taking a random sub-sample of these IMO should worsen the model. Maybe I'm missing something, just some thoughts on the linked post @desertnaut

Comment: As I mention explicitly in the linked answer, the fact that random feature selection alone improves performance is well-established. I agree that it's not very intuitive - perhaps it can be thought of (*very* roughly) as a "lasso-type" regularization. But the main point of my comment was not that, but the normal & recommended use of `max_features`, which I happily see you have incorporated in the answer ;)